# Youtube API batch processing to get user's subscriptions

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I'm trying to get the user's subscriptions list. You can only get 50 at a time so i would like to create a batch processing to do all at once.

I'm using Jquery and ajax to send a POST request like this :

```
var query = "<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'";
query += "xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'";
query += "xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'"
query += "xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>";

for(var i = 0; i < loop; ++i)
{
    query += '<entry>';
    query += '<id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' + youtube_username + '/subscriptions?max-results=50&start-index=' + ((i * 50) + 1) + '&alt=json</id>';
    query += "<batch:operation type='query'/>";
    query += '</entry>';
}

query += '</feed>';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/batch?v=2',
    data: query,
    contentType:"application/atom+xml",
    dataType:"xml",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

When I do this request I get an error 400 (bad url request). Then I tried with this URL for entries :

```
query += '<id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' + youtube_username + '/subscriptions/</id>';
```

But I got this error :

> Element type "feed" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Thank you and have a nice day,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Batch processing requests support query (GET) operations for feed entries but not for entire feeds. For example, if you are sending a batch request for a playlist, you can include one or more entries that retrieve information about individual playlist entries. However, the batch request cannot retrieve the playlist feed that contains those entries.", as documented in https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_batch_processing

I prefer explain on this way:

- Assume **subscriptions** is what you want process with batch. You open
  http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/subscriptions?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=True
- 1. Navigate the entry, extract entry id. The id is not extract from **id": {"$t": "tag:youtube.com,2008:user:google:subscriptions"}** or **tag:youtube.com,2008:user:google:subscription:X7RMFNKroIVT2j3zlJcZK2BI2_ZLB1PH1-0aiYV1oMo**, you should find the **link** tag with **self**, that means you extract the id from **link's self** tag. The id would be **http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/subscriptions/X7RMFNKroIVT2j3zlJcZK7VKfC7MoH_jycANXotcvEI?v=2**. One more thing, the **link** tag is inside **entry** tag, not inside **feed**. If you extract it from **feed**, you would get **http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/subscriptions?alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=25&v=2** which is wrong.
- 1. And finally, request API. Example of using curl is:
     **`curl -vLk -d "<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'><batch:operation type='query'/><entry><id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/subscriptions/X7RMFNKroIVT2j3zlJcZK7VKfC7MoH_jycANXotcvEI?v=2</id></entry></feed>" -X POST "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/subscriptions/batch?v=2"`**

Another example is video, such as:

**curl -vLk -d "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/EWKcFuluXpo" -X POST "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/batch?v=2"**

And **user/channel's info** example, such as:

**curl -vLk -d "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers" -X POST "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/batch?v=2"**

So, i don't think it's possible query list of subscriptions by batch processing, without knowing the entry id in the first place.